# SharePoint 2013: Display custom field in search results

Tags: 2013, search

I have been doing research on this for a while and come up with nothing. I have a site with several document libraries, and each document library has a custom "Abstract" column, containing a brief description for each document.

**How can I display the Abstract field instead of the description automatically gleaned from the documents?**

[image: Would like to replace this with a custom description for each file.]

I would rather use the default search page (/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx) than a custom results page if possible! It's worth noting that **I do not have server access**.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

The answer would be **Item Display Templates**. You will need to convert your custom Abstract Column to a managed property and create a custom item display template which displays this managed property for your search results.

Here is good post on how to turn your own custom column to appear in search results. http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-customized-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I did notice that the article above does not talk about how to create managed property (They have used pages as an example). In order to create your abstract column as a managed property, you will have to go to Central Admin and under Search Service Application, go to Search Schema and create a new Managed Property. This property should be bound to the crawled property for your abstract column. (The crawled property should already exist if there is data in your column and a crawl has been run). In order to see results under the managed property, make sure a full/incremental crawl has been run.